# How to send email to multiple recipients by phpmail

Tags: phpmailer

I would like to know how to send email to multiple recipients by phpmailer while the email address is input by the user at the front-end rather than hard-code the address at the back-end.

Please kindly advise.
Thanks,
Wayne

Answer (score 0):

Passing the emails and names to your script, and then simply calling the AddAddress method when you're processing the incoming information would do it.

It isn't clear from your question whether you want to have multiple or single recipients.. it's a little contradictory.  Here's a basic example for multiple recipients with their names and emails in an array:

```
require 'class.phpmailer.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;

/* 
  set up your email here... 
*/

foreach ($recipients as $email => $name) {
    $mail->AddAddress($email, $name); 
} 

/* 
  Then send your email.. 
*/
```

What have you tried?

Comment: Thanks Musturdy,
I tried but I don't know how to retrieve the multiple email address at the front end, for example there are the text field to input multiple email address and separate by comma.

====Front end====
<input name="email_address" id="label" type="text" class="itext" maxlength="" value=""  />

====Back end====
$email_address= array($_REQUEST['email_address']);

foreach( $email_addressas $send){
  $mail->AddAddress($send);
}


It is only available to send a single email address but not multiple address, please advise.

Comment: Can you post that in your original question?  It's very difficult to see it here.  you can use `explode(',', $email_address)` and separate the string by commas to get an array of the emails.. then just call the `$mail->AddAddress()` method once for each one...  http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: Hi Musturdy,
I am agree that it looks difficult to read the post, I want to reply the post in original question too but I can not find any "Reply" button...I just find the "Answer Your Question" button only...I may try to use it.